How to Quote Custom Products in Odoo Without a Full BOM?
I am working with a business that specializes in custom clothing, particularly workwear. By "custom," I mean incorporating branding and other personalized elements.
Current Process: Currently, when I provide a quote, about one-third of the products proceed to production without further modification. However, we often need to adjust details like logo sizes or T-shirt colours (totally understandable). Our current process involves manually determining materials, accounting for manufacturing costs, and adding a safeguard percentage. This is all done using Excel, as we haven't found software that meets our needs.
Challenges: Since these products are unique and have never been produced before, our cost estimates are rough, aimed at ensuring a good profit margin. The challenge is how to calculate all these costs in Odoo without creating a complete Bill of Materials (BOM) and production-ready product details until an order is confirmed. Essentially, I want to stay on the quote page and avoid dealing with BOMs and other specifics that might change later. (Could be totally scrapped to)
Desired Solution: A colleague shared an image that seems to represent what we're looking for. The "SPECSPEC" line is what the customer will see, and the other columns summarize details for the four underlying products only visible internaly.
enter image description here
Objective: The goal is to significantly reduce the time spent creating quotes.
I hope this explanation is clear. Your feedback and any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

There's a nifty post about this recently updated on odoo forums: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/manufacturing-order-customized-as-per-the-customers-order-200517
